# NSDocumentDirectory - write to & read from file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

This is the code used to write to a file from contents of `UITextFields` (name,addr,contactNumber,email).

```
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          self.name.text, @"UserName"
                          ,self.address.text, @"UserAddress"
                          ,self.contactNumber.text, @"UserContactNumber"
                          ,self.email.text, @"UserEmail"
                          , nil];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDetails"];
BOOL writtenToFile = [userDict writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"writtenToFile: %d",writtenToFile);
```

and this one to read from file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsPath];
for (NSString *path in directoryEnumerator)
{
    NSLog(@"File Names: %@", path);
    if ([path isEqualToString:@"UserDetails"]) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
        NSDictionary *userDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSLog(@"%@",userDict);
    }
}
```

But it is failing to read anything. All time it prints null in logs.

```
File Names: UserDetails
(null)
(null)
```

Comment: Please include your actual logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add extra **'Path'** when reading

```
NSString *documentsPath =  [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDetails"];
```

**Edit**

Then, provide full path to **dataWithContentsOfFile:** . Enumerate will give you the name of file only

Comment: I already found the file & thats why it is printing in `NSLog`. Still tried your line. Sorry bro this line didn't worked for me.

Comment: you path only 'UserDetails'. How **dataWithContentsOfFile:** gonna search file with only that information?

Comment: you should provide full path

Comment: Fantastic dude.. It worked. Add your previous comments to answers. BTW I already accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] path];
//You'll need an additional '/'
NSString *fullPath = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"/UserDetails.plist"];
BOOL writtenToFile = [userDict writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Tried this too. *NO SUCCESS*. After putting breakpoint it showed me `data - variable is not NSData` & `userDict - nil`